# Interesting functional equation from a Greek math contest

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

> Find a function $f:\Bbb R^+\to\Bbb R$ that is strictly increasing and satisfies:
>
> $f(x) > -\frac1x$ for all $x > 0$
>
> $f(x)f\left(f(x)+\frac1x\right) = 1$ for all $x > 0$

**Attempt:**

If $f(x)+\frac1x= g(x),$ then
$f(x) = \frac1{f(g(x))}.$

Replace $x$ with $g(x).$ Then, we get

$$f(g(x)) = \frac1{f(g(g(x)))}$$

and so, $$f(x) = f(g(g(x)))$$

If we assume $f$ is injective, this means $$\begin{aligned}g(g(x)) = x\\f(g(x)) + 1/g(x) = x\\\frac1{f(x)} + \frac1{f(x) + 1/x} = x.\end{aligned}$$

This leads to a quadratic in $f(x)$ which finally gives

$$f(x) = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4/x}}2$$

Now, to complete this, I need to find non - injective functions $f$ which also satisfy this (or prove that none exist). Since I didn't use the first condition at all, I think there are some non-injective solutions, but I cannot find them.

Comment: Call $y=f(x)$. I got $x^2 y^2-x y-1=0$ and so $y=f(x)=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2 x}$. Both of them satisfy the functional equation and the condition to be greater than $-\frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$

Comment: A) You used the condition that $ f(x) > 1/x$ in order to justify taking $ f(g(x) )$, IE You needed to ensure that $ g(x) \in R^+$, otherwise that would have been meaningless. B) Agree with Raffaele that you solved the final question incorrectly. C) Can you check if this contest problem requires you to find all solutions, or just one? (The latter isn't that common, since it allows people to make various assumptions.) IE It is reasonable to guess that a potential answer looks like $f(x) = a/x$, and then determine $a$.

Comment: Why would you look for non-injective functions? The question asks you to find strictly increasing, i.e. injective solutions